# i used inAppPurchase in my appwhere didReceiveResponse method never called but every time didFailedWithError Called

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

i am trying to add in App Purchase in my app. i have done this code. Object of SKProductsRequest is Global.

```
-(void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler {

_completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];
_productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
_productsRequest.delegate = self;
[_productsRequest start];
}
```

in above method _productIdentifiers display a correct value when i debug it. my SKProductsRequest Delegate method is here.

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
_productsRequest = nil;
NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
        NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
        skProduct.productIdentifier,
        skProduct.localizedTitle,
        skProduct.price.floatValue);
    }
_completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
_completionHandler = nil;
}

-(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Failed to load list of products.");
_productsRequest = nil;
_completionHandler(NO, nil);
_completionHandler = nil;
}
```

my problem is that every time it calls didFailWithError method but never called didReceiveResponse method.
i hope someone help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error it gives you?

Comment: Try it from device, not in simulator.

Comment: @wain Failed to load list of products.

Comment: @quadDef I am using device but can't get appropriate result.

Comment: Have you ever seen it work? How are the products defined in iTunesConnect? What status are they in? What are the identifiers?

Comment: @Wain No it never worked. status is ready to Submit. Identifier is com.idev.inAppPurchase.IAP1

Comment: thanks Wain and quadDef for help me but now i solved my issue.